# SQL Server: capture table updates only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

### Question

*Is there any generic (reusable between multiple tables) and easy to implement/understand way to capture only updates at SQL Server table?*

### Objective

I have SQL Server 2012 SP4 transactional replica. I'm reading (loading) multiple 10GB+ tables on daily basis from SQL Server to my cloud storage.

It appears those 10GB+ tables aren't 100% immutable: 98-99% of operations are inserts, BUT 1-2% - updates.

### Mitigations

1. *Full table load* 

   It requires more resources at Nifi side, but the implementation is very
   simple and straighforward
2. *Incremental load by ID column plus capture last day updates with triggers* 

   Performance-wise but it is more complex: it requires configuring triggers on SQL 
    Server side plus reducing multiple versions of row (updates) on ETL layer.
3. *Generate `MODIFIEDAT` column during replication for all tables*

   It would be greate, but I think very hard to impossible: we don't have right to modify master database.

CDC looks like not an option because 98-99% of operations are inserts, means CDC will duplicate tables/database volume almost twice. AFAIK, from [SQL Server CDC doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-enable-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378532/change-data-capture-for-updates-and-deletes-only) it looks like SQL Server CDC can't be configured to capture updates only.

Comment: Do you have control over the publication? If so, there are parameters in `sp_addarticle` that control what happens on inserts, updates, and deletes (`@ins_cmd`, etc). If you only want to replicate updates, set the other two operations to 'NONE'.

Comment: @BenThul unfortunatelly I haven't got controll over inserting/updating, that is done by other applications developed far ago by other teams/companies

Comment: When I say the publication though, I mean specifically the setup of replication at the source database. Without being able to do *something* at the source, I think your options are rather limited.

Comment: @BenThul you can't solve that problem on level of replication. Example, you have table of 20 billions of rows. The table has 10M inserts and 10K updates daily. You want to read only 10M + 10K rows from replica. 10M are easy to read - you can store watermark (ID) and query `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE ID > watermark`. CDC was needed to read those 10K daily updates. By not replicating inserts - you won't be able to read 10M of daily inserts from replica. Are you proposing create another DB replica to bypass CDC limitations?